# In R K-means, can we see objective function value over iterations?

Tags: r, matlab, optimization, cluster-analysis, k-means

In [matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html), we can see the details of the optimization process for Kmeans

[image]

Can we do similar thing in R (enable trace will produce some informaiton, but I do not know what those means)?

```
d=iris[,c(3,4)]
>kmeans(d, 2,nstart=1, trace=4)
KMNS(*, k=2): iter=  1, indx=43
 QTRAN(): istep=150, icoun=56, NCP[1:2]= 244 244
 QTRAN(): istep=300, icoun=92, NCP[1:2]= 358 358
```

Comment: Did you check out the `?kmeans` help page? Does `trace=TRUE` not do what you want?

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks for your comment. But I do not understand the trace information.

Comment: @MrFlick I edited my question according to your suggestions.